# Why we need std::partition_point whereas we can use std::find_if_not algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my possible implementation of the algorithm `std::partition_point` is :

```
template <typename In_It, typename FUNC>
In_It partitionPoint(In_It b, In_It e, FUNC pred){
    int len = e - b;

    while (len > 0){
        int half = len >> 1;
        In_It middle = b + half;
        if( pred(*middle) ){
            b = middle;
            ++b;
            len = len - half - 1;
        }
        else
            len = half;
    }
      return b;
}
```

My code looks like the STL one apart from using `std::distance`, `traits`... So it examines the input sequence and returns an iterator to the past-last element in the sequence for which the predicate succeeds. In other words the returned iterator denotes an element that doesn't satisfy the predicate.

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12};
    auto it = partitionPoint(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x){return x % 2; });

    if( it != v.cend() )
        std::cout << *it << " " << it - v.cbegin() << '\n';
}
```

- The output:

  ```
  6 at index: 7
  ```

It is OK. however why I don't use directly `std::find_if_not` which returns an iterator to the first element for which the predicate is false?

```
 auto it2 = findIfNot(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int x){return x % 2; });
 if(it2 != v.cend())
    std::cout << *it2 << " at index: " << it2 - v.cbegin() << '\n';
```

The output:

```
  6 at index: 7
```

Comment: Maybe you can use it.   There are probably other algorithms that can be expressed in terms of other algorithms.  I would advise taking a look at the implementation on your compiler, to see if they employed any optimization tricks for `std;:partition_point`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::find_if_not` has `O(N)` complexity as it does a linear traversal.  `std::partition_point` on the other hand has `O(logN)` complexity as it takes advantage the fact that the set is partitioned and does a binary search to find the element.  Depending on the situation, this could be a big performance win.

Comment: OK! I get it. I missed that point! binary search. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa No worries.  Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are always so helpful. In fact for the understanding and education purposes I've written many algorithms that simulate to the STL ones.